# PHP: Stuffing CURL's Cookiejar into a $Session varaible?

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

As I understand it, curl uses the cookiefile parameter to read the cookies, and cookiejar to save them once the curl session is completed.

Typical examples for using this indicate a file must be used, but I don't want to need manual cleanup of these leftover bits.
For example, if I set the cookiejar to a file using tempnam, I will inevitably end up with a directory full of little cookiejars that I will need to clean up.

IF the user properly logs out, I can of course delete this temp file, but I'm counting on a majority of the users just closing the browser window and the session (eventually) expiring, leaving me with no way to delete the cookie jar automatically.

My best idea thus far is to splash a cookiejar into the temp folder, read it into a session variable, and then delete the cookiejar file every time curl is used.

Previous users' implementations is to obviate the cookiejar by parsing header information, but this is a little more involved that I want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to go the temp-file wraparound method. Assuming your curl handler is named $c:

```
//Put down the cookieJar
$cookieJar = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),"cookie-");
if (isset($_SESSION['c_Cookies'])) file_put_contents($cookieJar,   $_SESSION['c_Cookies']);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
```

and at the end of the script:

```
//Always destroy curl, just in case...
curl_close ($c);
unset($c);
//And pickup the cookieJar
$_SESSION['c_Cookies'] = file_get_contents($cookieJar);
unlink($cookieJar);
```

This of course assumes the system temp directory is writable by whoever is running php. It should ensure that the cookiejar is always deleted at the end of the script, so long as said script does not terminate prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *parsing* them, you could just pass-through the headers between your clients and the other server. Just remember to add a regex replace for the "domain=[^;]+" part in the set-cookie case.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, so long as the reflected server doesn't care about the foreign cookies being passed from my server. I'll try it and see!